# How to display image in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have imported the **import { Avatar } from '@material-ui/core';** to display the image using the avatar

```
const TheHeader = () => {
  let _UsersId = localStorage.getItem("UsersId")
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [reRender, setRerender] = useState(false);
  const [profilepic, setprofilepic] = useState();
  const getProfile = async () => {
    const response = await Profile(_UsersId);
    setprofilepic(response.data)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getProfile();
  }, [reRender, profilepic]);
 .....


  <Avatar alt="" src={profilepic} className={classes.avatar}/>
```

the result is like this (current)

[image]

desired result

[image]

result from api   `console.log(response)`

[image]

Comment: You have the wrong image format, you need to convert it to "data URL"

Answer (score 0):

Currently what is being displayed is the fallback image by the `Avatar` component of material ui.
This is maybe because the image url you are serving it, might be being fetched **AFTER** your `Avatar` component has loaded.
The solution to this would - reload the `Avatar` component using `useEffect` with image URL set as an observable.
Sample code :

```
const TheHeader = () => {
  let _UsersId = localStorage.getItem("UsersId")
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [profilepic, setprofilepic] = useState();
  const getProfile = async () => {
    const response = await Profile(_UsersId);
    setprofilepic(response.data[0].ProfilePhoto)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getProfile();
  }, [profilepic]);
 .....


  <Avatar alt="" src={profilepic} className={classes.avatar}/>
```

Now, once your img url is fetched from the endpoint, your component will reload with the correct image in place

Comment: its still the same.

Comment: ok can you just do this. Add `console.log('I am rendered')` as a executable in this component and send a screenshot of the console. I want to see how it is rendering. Also, I checked out `Avatar` docs at material ui and the example images they seem to be displaying are kind of locally stored, which is causing this error, but that's a very low possibility

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Update `getProfile` function to create *objectUrl* from binary data:

```js
  const getProfile = async () => {
    const response = await Profile(_UsersId);
    const buffer = new Uint8Array(response.data)
    const blob = new Blob([buffer])
    setprofilepic(URL.createObjectURL(blob))
  }
```

Comment: How about in jsx?

Comment: <Avatar alt="" src={profilepic} className={classes.avatar}/> like this?

Comment: I've tried your answer and nothing display